What is the best practice to update React Native, Expo and its dependecies?
I have been using the following versions since the inception of my project. Currently, I am uncertain about the reasons to update or not. However, as I am now beginning to incorporate native features like push notifications, I am concerned about potential conflicts due to never having updated these dependencies before.
"expo": "~46.0.19", "react": "18.0.0", "react-native": "0.69.6",
The answer if I have to update the libs.
